# Perpendicular line from a median in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, median

In the right triangle ABC where ∠B = 90◦
, BC : AB = 1 : 2. Construct the median BD
and let point E be on BD such that CE ⊥ BD. Determine BE : ED
(Figure below)

I already solved this problem, but the methods I used were really long and maybe there is a property that makes things a lot easier in this problem.

I already tried using coordinate geometry and trigonometry, the coordinate geometry is pretty straight forward so I'll only show the trigonometry solution

Trig Solution:

By Pythagorean Theorem, $DC = \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$, By Cosine Law on triangle CDB, We see that $BD =  \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$.

We know that

$\sin (DCE) = \frac{2DE}{\sqrt5}$

$\sin (BCE) = BE$

$\sin(BCE + DCE) = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}$

Using these equations, we can find that

$CE(BE + ED) = 1$

then $CE = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}$

Using Pythagorean on CDE and CBE, we find that the ratio  of the 2 lengths is 2:3.

Any solution that is different from these is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(0,2)$, $B(0,0)$, $C(1,0)$, hence $D(1/2,1)$. The straight line through $BD$, $y=2x$, meets the line through $CE$, $y=-x/2+1/2$, for $x=1/5$, the first coordinate of $E$.  Since the first coordinate of $D$ is $1/2$, it follows that
$$BE:ED=\frac{1}{5}:\left(\frac12-\frac15\right)=2:3.$$